# Android get text of EditText elements in a dialog

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to write data, users put in my review dialog to the database using json.
Everything works except getting the text of the two fields.. If I hard code 2 string everything is fine and writes as it should.

Here is my code

```
private void writeReview() {
    EditText ETUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    String username = ETUsername.getText().toString();

    EditText ETMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dialog_review);
    String message = ETMessage.getText().toString();

    Review review = new Review(username, message, retailerId.toString(),
            "8Hr------U");
    JsonHelper jsonHelper = new JsonHelper();

    HttpWriter httpWriter = new HttpWriter();
    httpWriter.setJsonObject(jsonHelper.getJsonReview(review));
    httpWriter
```

The dialog --------------------------------

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:hint="@string/dialog_username" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/dialog_review"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:hint="@string/dialog_review" />
<!--     <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Is it maybe because the two fields are into a dialog and the activity cannot reach it like I try to do it?

If you can help me - many thanks and happy holidays.

Comment: Where is the method writeReview() called from?

Comment: When you press the Send button in the dialog. Everything works fine it's just that I cannot get the text out of the fields..

Comment: What do you mean by 'activity cannot reach it'? Are you calling writeReview() from the activity (from one of activity's callbacks) ? Also, what exactly goes wrong? Do you get an exception? Are strings returned by getText() empty?

Comment: Problem is that Strings username and message bug when I try to get their values.

Review review = new Review("username", "message", retailerId.toString(), "8Hr------U"); <- this for example works

Comment: Could you answer my questions? Otherwise I cannot fully understand the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the EditText variables (ETusername and ETmessage) class variable and inflate it into onCreate() method of activity.

find edit text with dialog view
EditText ETUsername = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.username);

Comment: It does not find the dialog.findViewById

Comment: Can you please share the code how are you creating and launching dialog?